# If I disable the submit button on submit, form is submitted without posting form fields

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui

If I disable the submit button on submit, the button is disabled and the form is submitted. However, the form is posted without posting the other form fields.

My HTML code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" >
    <input name="test" value="" />
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn_save">Save</button>
</form>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $( ".btn_save" ).button( "disable" );
    });
});


$(function() {
    $( ".btn_save" ).button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-check"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `.button()` method? Boostrap one or what? At least, add reference to plugin in question

Comment: Also put `HTML` code.

Comment: can you please post your html form code?

Comment: If you are using jQuery UI or some other ui library, add it as a tag or mention it in your question. jQuery and html forms don't have a `.button` method.

Comment: No problem. I have added the html, the complete jquery code and jquery-ui tag.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in order to disable button you need to use attr property of jquery , if you want the button to disable after submit . if you getting no post values after submitting , try to check the < form > properties like method, action . Try to use selector as ID ( #formID )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formid').submit(function() {
       $( ".btn_save" ).attr( "disabled", true );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I use the attr property the form submits correct, but the button is not disabled, or at least not displayed disabled. (I use Chrome).

Comment: It doesn't really show anything different I suppose, but it is disabled.

Comment: Try to  $( ".btn_save" ).attr("disabled", true);

Comment: The point is `.button( "disabled" )` updates the display of the button, but does not properly disable it. do both to get both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $( ".btn_save" ).button({ disabled: true });
    });
});
```

See [Button Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled)

Comment: Thanks but thats how to set an option. I used the method.